# NullPointerException during downloading data with retrofit2

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nullpointerexception, retrofit2

I have NullPointerException during downloading data from my API using retrofit2. I extricated inner callback in my `DataService` class and I call it in fragment `ListFragment` to download the data. `ListFragment` has implemented `RecyclerView` and will be displaying that data. For now, I want to display only two textViews. Layout for them has name `single_data_layout`. `List<Feature> features` is my `DataResponse`. Anyone any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Maybe you know some examples with existing callbacks from retrofits equeue()?
There aren't many online.

You can find the whole project on [GitHub](https://github.com/lwach87/EarthquakeApp)

Stacktrace:

```
03-08 09:32:46.913 17938-17938/com.example.lwach.earthquakeapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.lwach.earthquakeapp, PID: 17938
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.lwach.earthquakeapp.apiClient.DataService.getData(retrofit2.Callback)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.lwach.earthquakeapp.ListFragment.onCreateView(ListFragment.java:33)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2189)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:757)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2355)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2146)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2098)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1979)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:626)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1268)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1116)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1642)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:714)
    at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
    at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1375)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:784)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:721)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:721)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2897)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2248)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1306)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1548)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1191)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6642)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
```

ApiClient:

```
public interface ApiClient {

    @GET("query")
    Call<DataResponse> getData(@QueryMap Map<String, String> options);
}
```

ApiClientFactory:

```
public class ApiClientFactory {

    public static final String baseURL = "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/";

    public ApiClient createApiClient(){
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseURL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        return retrofit.create(ApiClient.class);
    }
}
```

DataService:

```
public class DataService {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private final ApiClient apiClient;
    private List<Feature> features;
    private Map<String, String> map;

    public DataService() {
        apiClient = new ApiClientFactory().createApiClient();
    }

    Callback<DataResponse> responseCallback = new Callback<DataResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<DataResponse> call, Response<DataResponse> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                features = response.body().getFeatures();
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "Data successfully downloaded");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<DataResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
        }
    };

    public void getData(Callback<DataResponse> callback) {

        map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("format", "geojson");
        map.put("minsig", "700");

        apiClient.getData(map).enqueue(callback);
    }
}
```

DataAdapter:

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.DataViewHolder> {

    private final List<Feature> features;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private ListFragment listFragment;

    public DataAdapter(List<Feature> features, ListFragment listFragment) {
        this.features = features;
        this.listFragment = listFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public DataViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_data_layout, parent, false);
        return new DataViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DataViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.place.setText(features.get(position).getProperties().getPlace());
        holder.alert.setText(features.get(position).getProperties().getAlert());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return features.size();
    }

    public static class DataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final TextView place;
        private final TextView alert;

        public DataViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            place = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.place_text_view);
            alert = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.alert_text_view);
        }
    }
}
```

ListFragment:

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment {

    private List<Feature> features;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private DataAdapter dataAdapter;
    private DataService dataService;
    private Callback<DataResponse> callback;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);

        dataService.getData(callback);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        dataAdapter = new DataAdapter(features, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this in ListFragment you haven't initialized DataService dataService ? Initialize it dataService = new DataService(); and try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't initialized `DataService`
in which `apiClient` variable is initialized in its constructor. so Direct call will not invoke its constructor.

Use this.

```
dataService = new DataService();
dataService.getData(callback);
```

in onCreateView of your ListFragment.

`apiClient` variable is initialized in

```
public DataService() {
        apiClient = new ApiClientFactory().createApiClient();
    }
```

So when you direct call like `dataService.getData(callback);` will not invoke its constructor so

```
apiClient.getData(map).enqueue(callback);
```

will produce **nullpointerexception. because `apiClient` variable is null**.

Comment: I totally forgot. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad to here that..:)

Comment: Sometimes the easiest things are the hardest :)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized DataService in ListFragment.

Initialize it before use that object.

```
dataService = new DataService();
```

and call

```
dataService.getData(callback);
```